# AdMob/iAd - Do impressions count when ad view is in scroll view?

Tags: android, ios, scrollview, admob, iad

Does the ad view need to always be visible for an impression to count? Such as could the ad view be at the bottom of a scroll view out of sight until the user reaches the bottom. Most ad views implementations I have seen have the ad view static on top of any content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is against apple's design docs to put ads in scrollable content. It would probably count but you will risk rejection. Another problem is that it needs time to fill an ad so you'd likely end up getting more ad requests and not enough fills and it will appear to be click fraud.

On that note I have accomplished a very hacked version of what you're asking. I had an add not be within the tableview but rather float with it and "clip" to the top or the bottom. The biggest problem with putting an ad in a tableview cell is it gets recycled every time it scrolls off the view. In the end I'd recommend just accepting putting the at statically on the top or bottom.

Comment: So the adbannerview will keep requesting an ad but won't fill the banner until the scroll view has scrolled to its location? I was under the impression scroll view contents loaded and displayed even when it's out of view, such as a UIImageView is still loaded even though not instantly in view. Or does adbannerview detect this?

Comment: The ad will only request when the view is created which is when the user is on the section of the table that has an ad it will request. It probably wouldn't fill if it was scrolled quickly past though